# PHP - Difference between connecting to SQL Server with or without port with PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I wanted to know if there is a real difference between

```
$connexion = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=xxxxxx;database=xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
```

and

```
$connexion = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=xxxxxx,1433;database=xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
```

I know the default port for SQL Server is 1433 but I wondered if PDO complete automatically the port by 1433 if it isn't specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give port it connects you on that port. If you don't give any port then it connects you default port

Answer (score 0):

Every MSSQL server instance runs on its own port number. You can configure the MSSQL Server instance to use a fixed port number instead of a dynamic one (which is the default).

Once you've configure a fixed port, you can simply connect to that port number using PDO.